# How to send Azure's custom voice model TTS request

Tags: azure, request, text-to-speech

I trained and deployed a custom voice model at Azure with no problem. Yet I couldn't get the TTS request to work.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/blob/master/Samples-Http/Python/TTSSample.py
is an example sending TTS request to *standard* models, not custom models.

According to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstart-python-text-to-speech,
the request body should be in plain text for custom model. I ended up doing something like:

```
response = requests.post(constructed_url, headers=headers, data='test 1')
```

in place of Line #65 in the python script, and delete all preceding request body specifications.

What I got is an error message:

```
Status code: 400
Something went wrong. Check your subscription key and headers.
```

The original python script with standard model worked just fine.

By the way, my resource is at south east asia; the language of my custom model is zh-cn.

Comment: Go to `https://cris.ai`, browse to your voice font (https://westus.cris.ai/CustomVoice/TestDeployEntry), there should be a Test button, check `F12 Developer Tools > Network` in your browser and borrow the payload from the request.

Comment: Looking at mine, it's form data `Text=Hey+hey+you+can't+impeach+me!&DeploymentId=0822e8a7-0e6b-421c-85c7-2096a9ec258a&Locale=en-US&VoiceName=Trumpfont&__RequestVerificationToken=fpExxxxxxxNnxg2`. Request URL is `https://<region>.cris.ai/CustomVoice/GetWaveDataFromDeployedService`

Comment: It appears that the [*.cris.ai](https://cris.ai) is totally a different portal other than [MS's portal](https://speech.microsoft.com/portal/). Anyway, I went through the entire process (upload/train/deploy) again. It does provide a test webpage. Problem solved! Thanks!

Comment: Custom Speech (speech recognition) and Custom Voice (text to speech with trained voice // cris.ai) are two completely different/distinct services. A little confusing but it is what it is.